# Возврат по ссылке файлового потока С++

Tags: c++, fstream

Вот есть такой кусочек кода:

```
   std::ifstream& save_files(const std::string& n) 
{
     std::ofstream file(n);
     for (int i(0); i < 100; i++)
     file << -50 + rand() % 101 << std::endl;
     file.close();
     return std::ifstream(n);
}

template <class T>
std::vector<T>& inputfile(std::ifstream& f)
{
    std::cout << f.get() << std::endl;  // BUG
    std::istream_iterator<T> iter(f);
    std::vector<T> result(100);
    while (iter != std::istream_iterator<int>())
       result.push_back(*iter++);
     return result;
 }

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v = inputfile<int>(save_files("numbers.txt"));
}
```

Почему-то, при возврате из функции save_files теряется ссылка на файл, соответственно чтение не производится. Подскажите, как правильно вернуть ссылку на поток?

Comment: Вы возвращаете ссылку на локальный объект?

Comment: ....прошу прощения. Исправил, вопрос закрыт. И спасибо :)

Comment: @Range, ради интереса - верните константную ссылку, и посмотрите, что будет :)

Comment: уже попробовал...эхх я)